# use Thymleaf and spring met org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am running a springboot demo,integrated with Thymleaf.But it keep throwing the following exeption:

> WARN 25302 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: "form.html"]**

**controller**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private List<User> getUserlist() {
        return userRepository.listUser();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userList", getUserlist());
        model.addAttribute("title", "user management");
        return new ModelAndView("users/list", "userModel", model);
    }

    @GetMapping("/form")
    public ModelAndView createForm(Model model) {
        User user=new User();
        user=userRepository.saveOrUpateUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("title", "create user");
        return new ModelAndView("users/form", "userModel", model);
    }
```

list.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:text="${userModel.title}">welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}">...</div>
<h3 th:text="${userModel.title}">Welcome to baidu.com</h3>
<div>
    <a href="/users/form.html">create user</a>
</div>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:if="${userModel.userList.size()} eq 0">
        <td colspan="3">no user info！！</td>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="user : ${userModel.userList}">
        <td th:text="${user.id}">1</td>
        <td th:text="${user.age}">11</td>
        <td><a href="view.html" th:href="@{'/users/' + ${user.id}}"
               th:text="${user.name}">waylau</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:text="${userModel.title}">users : View</title>
</head>s
<body>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}">...</div>
<h3 th:text="${userModel.title}">Welcome to baidu.com</h3>
<div>
    <a href="/users">back to home</a>
</div>
<form action="/users" method="POST" th:object="${userModel.user}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}">
    名称:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" th:value="*{name}">
    <br>
    年龄:<br>
    <input type="text" name="age" th:value="*{age}">
    <input type="submit" value="提交">
</form>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
 User.java
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement // mediatype 转为xml
public class User {

    private long id; // 用户的唯一标识
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    ....getter and setter
}
```

on the home page,everything goes fine,except the **[create user](/users/form.html)** anchor which should return a form to fill.

any idea?

Comment: Thy this: Change your controller annotation to @Controller (not @RestController) and change your link to <a href="users/form">Create user</a> (without the .html)...

Comment: Also your form action points to "/users" - this will also get you in trouble since it's annotated with @GetMapping (not accepting post-requests).

Comment: from **href="users/form.html"** to **href="users/form"** ,just donot quite understand why it says ***Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long';**